# Can't submit because "blur" is taking charge

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, submit

I want to show submit button after clicking on a text.

So, the HTML looks like that:

```
 <td align="left" class="editable_td">
  <form action='cms/content/save/2' type='POST'>
   <p class="editable seo" >{{ news['nazwa']|raw }}
   </p>
   <input type='submit' name='submit' class='button2' style='display:none;' value='change title'>
 </form>
</td>
```

and my jquery:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

       $('.button2').on('click',function() {
         alert(2);
        });

       var text;
       var klasa;

       $(".editable_td").on("click", "p.editable",function() {
         var parent = $(this).parent();
         text = $(this).text();
         klasa = $(this).attr('class');
         $(this).siblings('.button2').show();
         $(this).replaceWith("<input class='editable_text' name='nazwa' type='text' value='"+text+"'>");
         parent.children(":text").focus();
         return false;
       });

       $(".editable_td").on("blur", '.editable_text',function() {
         $(this).siblings('.button2').hide();
         $(this).replaceWith("<p class='editable "+klasa+"'>"+text+"</p>");
        });

});
```

of course i want to submit this form, not to alert(2), but even though i can't even alert() because after clicking on a button it simply disappears. How can i fix this? I don't want this button to be shown before clicking on this text.

**EDIT**

the answer is (as **James Donnelly** said ) to set timeout:

```
 setTimeout(function() {
    $(this).siblings('.button2').hide();
    $(this).replaceWith("<p class='editable "+klasa+"'>"+text+"</p>");
}, 1);
```

**BUT**

right now when I'm sending via POST my url looks like this:

**[mysite]cms/content/save/1?nazwa=Nazwa+++++++++++++++++++++&submit=change+title**
and here comes another problem which i can't solve :P
( it should be like this: **[mysite]cms/content/save/1 )

**SECOND EDIT:**

if anybody encounters this problem: set timeout to ~200, and then change form.method to post.

Comment: what...really...maybe stop hiding the submit button on `blur` event.

Comment: yeah, great answer ^^ so i will have text + button. Did you at least read my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can hackily cheat this to an extent using `setTimeout` with a delay of 1 millsecond within the `.on('blur')` function:

```
$(".editable_td").on("blur", '.editable_text',function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(this).siblings('.button2').hide();
        $(this).replaceWith("<p class='editable "+klasa+"'>"+text+"</p>");
    }, 1);
});
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/SRB2Y/1/).